# something that looks sort of symmetrical but also not

Tags: abstract-algebra, automata

Given the set $S_0$ of finite binary strings whose digit sum is congruent to 0 mod 2 and the set $S_1$ of finite binary strings whose digit sum is congruent to 1 mod 2,

what are the implications of the fact that $F: \{s_1 \in S_1 : s_1    \mbox{ends   in  1} \} \to S_0$ that removes the trailing 1 from $s_1$ is onto $S_0$ but  $“F^{-1}” : \{s_0 \in S_0 \} \to S_1$  that appends a 1 to the end of $s_0$ is not onto $S_1$?

Comment: Didn't you mean mod 2?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "what are the implications"?

Comment: When you write or edit a post, the result is shown below. you don't need to save the edit each time to see what happens...

Comment: @tomasz I'm on my mobile browser... And yes I did want to say mod 2 :)

Comment: I just saw a silver notification indicating there was a suggested edit but it said "rejected" at the bottom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a sense, this shows that you can add or subtract a single element from an infinite set and still have a bijection between the domain and range.  This is not true for finite sets.  If we allow $0 \in \mathbb N$, consider $f(x)=x+1$ on $\mathbb N$.  $f$ is not onto, but $f^{-1}$ is.  This is equivalent to your example, but may be less surprising.  One's view of the implications can range from "trivial" to "the base of all the theory of infinite sets".

Comment: Should your $f^{-1}$ be in quotes or something since it doesn't map 0 to anything?

Comment: @AbstractionOfMe:  $f^-1$ has a domain of $\mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$, it is true. It is still a fine function.  This is similar to the fact that your $F$ does not have a domain of all of $S_1$, which you made explicit.  It maps "half of $S_1$" onto $S_0$.